# Can't get right top of UIViewControllers view

Tags: ios, constraints, viewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a "notification" if there's no connection with the backend server.

Now, I have an ExceptionManager that generates an UIView that I want to show on the current viewControllers view. But when I try to do it in such a way as bellow, it places the view on the top of viewController's view BUT without taking into account the navigation bar.

How can i place the view right under the navigationBar on a custom view in my app?

```
- (void)showNoConnectionMessage
{
    UIViewController *currentController = [ExceptionManager getTopController];
    UIView *currentView = currentController.view;

    ExceptionMessageVC *exceptionMessageVC = [[ExceptionMessageVC alloc] initWithMessage:@"No connection!"];
    exceptionMessageVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [currentView addSubview:exceptionMessageVC.view];

    [currentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:exceptionMessageVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:currentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.1f constant:0]];
    [currentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:exceptionMessageVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:currentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.f constant:0]];

    [currentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:exceptionMessageVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:currentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
    [currentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:exceptionMessageVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:currentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
}

+ (UIViewController*) getTopController
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topViewController.presentedViewController) {
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topViewController;
}
```

Comment: You can answer your own question so that can find the solution for your problem more easily.

Answer (score 0):

When using contraints, you can use the `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` properties of the `UIViewController`. They take into account navigation bars and bottom bars.

Instead of this :

```
[currentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:exceptionMessageVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:currentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
```

Do this :

```
[currentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:exceptionMessageVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:currentController.topLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
```

Comment: Tried to do it like you recommended, but nothing changed :(

This is how it looks like - http://gyazo.com/d9cd3d5c72d4e166d294839f974200dc

Answer (score 0):

add your view like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window addSubview:exceptionMessageVC.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by modifying getTopController as bellow:

```
+ (UIViewController *)getTopController
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    if ([topViewController.childViewControllers.lastObject isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
    {
        topViewController = ((UITabBarController *) topViewController.childViewControllers.lastObject).selectedViewController;
    }

    if (topViewController.childViewControllers.lastObject)
        topViewController = topViewController.childViewControllers.lastObject;

    while (topViewController.presentedViewController)
    {
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topViewController;
}
```